# REST API Callout LWC

Tags: rest-api, lightning-web-components

I have created an LWC with a REST API call to grab data from and external DB. The data is fetched successfully and then rendered in the component. I would then like to create a record based on the data retrieved. I have tried an onchange Event for the fields but this doesn't work because the changes are done programmatically.

How can I either trigger the onNameChange or map the json response to variables which can be used when creating the record. I am new to LWC and JS so tips on best practice would be appreciated.

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Account Quick Create" icon-name="standard:account">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                    <lightning-layout-item>
                          <lightning-combobox
                             name="progress"
                             label="Country"
                             value=""
                             placeholder="Select a Country"
                             options={options}
                             onchange={handleChange}
                            required
                            ></lightning-combobox>
                    </lightning-layout-item>
                </div>
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
            <lightning-layout vertical-align="end" class="slds-m-bottom_small">

                <lightning-layout-item flexibility="grow">
                    <lightning-input
                        type="search"
                        onchange={handleSearchKeyChange}
                        label="Search businesses by organization number"
                        value={searchKey}
                    ></lightning-input>
                </lightning-layout-item>
                <lightning-layout-item class="slds-p-left_xx-small">
                    <lightning-button
                        label="Search"
                        onclick={handleSearchClick}
                    ></lightning-button>
                </lightning-layout-item>
            </lightning-layout>


            <template if:true={org}>
                    <lightning-input
                    type="hidden"
                    disabled
                    data-id="accountId"
                    value={accountId}
        ></lightning-input>

                    <lightning-input type="text" label="Name" placeholder="" value={org.navn} onchange={handleNameChange}></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" label="Address" placeholder="" value={org.forretningsadresse.adresse} disabled></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" label="Zip/Postal Code" placeholder="" value={org.forretningsadresse.postnummer} disabled></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="text" label="City" placeholder="" value={org.forretningsadresse.poststed} disabled></lightning-input>
                    <lightning-input type="number" label="Number of Employees" placeholder="" value={org.antallAnsatte} disabled></lightning-input>

                <div class="slds-align_absolute-center slds-m-around_medium">
                     <lightning-button 
                        label="Create Account"
                        variant="brand"
                        onclick={createAccount}
                    ></lightning-button>
                </div>


            </template>
            <!--
                render error message 

            <template if:true={error}>
                <c-error-panel errors={error}></c-error-panel>
            </template>

            -->
        </div>


    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
import { createRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Name';
import Address_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingAddress';
import Employee_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.NumberOfEmployees';




const QUERY_URL =
    'https://data.brreg.no/enhetsregisteret/api/enheter/';


export default class CreateAccount extends LightningElement {
    @track searchKey = '';
    @track org =false;
    @track error;
    @track accountId;


    name = '';


    get options() {
        return [
            { label: 'Test Picklist value', value: '' },
            { label: 'Test Picklist value', value: '' },
        ];
    }



    handleChange(event) {
        this.value = event.detail.value;
    }

    handleNameChange(event) {
        this.accountId = undefined;
        this.name = event.target.value;
   }


    handleSearchKeyChange(event) {
        this.searchKey = event.target.value;


    }

    handleSearchClick() {
        // The Fetch API is currently not polyfilled for usage in IE11.
        // Use XMLHttpRequest instead in that case.
        fetch(QUERY_URL + this.searchKey)
            .then(response => {
                // fetch isn't throwing an error if the request fails.
                // Therefore we have to check the ok property.
                if (!response.ok) {
                    this.error = response;
                }
                return response.json();

            })

            .then(jsonResponse => {
                this.org = jsonResponse;

            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.error = error;
                this.org = undefined;
            });

    }



    createAccount() {
        const fields = {};
        fields[NAME_FIELD.fieldApiName] = this.name;
        fields[Address_FIELD.fieldApiName] = '';
        fields[Employee_FIELD.fieldApiName] = '';
        const recordInput = { apiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT.objectApiName, fields };

        createRecord(recordInput)
            .then(account => {
                this.accountId = account.id;
                this.org=false;
                this.searchKey='';
                this.dispatchEvent(
                    new ShowToastEvent({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Account created',
                        variant: 'success'
                    })
                );
            })
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I struggled to make `lightning/uiRecordApi` work as well. You can use imperative apex to send JSON values and use it to create the record(s) using apex.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am able to display the response from the GET request in the UI. I would prefer to be able to use JS to store the response to variables which can then be used to create a record instead of using Apex. Any luck with this?

Answer (score 0):

Account.BillingAddress is a compound field.  Try breaking out the fields that comprise Billing Address and set those field values individually to create the record.

```
import ADDRESS_BILLINGSTREET_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingStreet';
import ACCOUNT_BILLINGCITY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingCity';
import ACCOUNT_BILLINGSTATE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingState';
import ACCOUNT_BILLINGPOSTALCODE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingPostalCode';
import ACCOUNT_BILLINGCOUNTRY_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.BillingCountry';
```